# How to save a large bitmap to the sdcard fast?

Tags: android

This is my current code to save the bitmap(2560x1440 resolution) to the sdcard:

```
private void saveImageToDiskTest()
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String fileName = "hid.png";
    String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/" + fileName;
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start_image_left);

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(completePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(elapsedTime), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It works, but it's very slow. It takes 10000ms to save the image. What can I do to speed up the process(with no loss of image quality)?

I am testing it on a Motorola Moto G gen2.

Comment: besides using a smaller image, nothing

Comment: since your operation takes long time to perform, why don't you use async task, or background thread. so you don't block the ui thread.

Comment: Well what type of image file is R.drawable.start_image_left? What is the reason that you first cumbersomly convert it to a bitmap and later to a png on file? If it is a png file you could better just copy it.